# Fabric js canvas into pdf(TCPDF)

Tags: php, json, pdf, canvas

I use fabric.js to draw some postcard(background, image, text). And I want to create pdf based on this card. So I send json object  to php and using foreach to get all element. But when i creating document on this same resolution (761x430) and setting margin, position and other value from json, the objects position in pdf is not this same as in fabric js. So what i should to do, that the position in my pdf was be the same like on canvas.
To create pdf i use TCPDF.

JSON File

```
{"objects":[{"type":"text","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":531.22,"top":249,"width":115,"height":31.2,"fill":"e2ddcf","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1.14,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","text":"MOJE TŁO","fontSize":24,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Times New Roman","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true},{"type":"image","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":63,"top":304,"width":66,"height":66,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":340.06,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","src":"src_to_picture","filters":[]}],"background":"cyan","backgroundImage":"src_to_my_picture","backgroundImageOpacity":1,"backgroundImageStretch":true}
```

PHP code

```
$pdf = new MYPDF("L", "px", array(761, 430), true, 'UTF-8', false, false, $objects->backgroundImage, $objects->background);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetRightMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    #$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    foreach ($objects->objects as $object) {
        $pdf->StartTransform();
        switch ($object->type) {
            case 'text':
                $align = $this->setAlign($object->textAlign);
                $style = $this->setStyle($object->fontStyle);
                $newColor = $this->hex2RGB($object->fill);
                $pdf->setXY($object->left, $object->top);
                $pdf->SetFont("times", $style, $object->fontSize);
                $pdf->SetTextColor($newColor['red'], $newColor['green'], $newColor['blue']);
                $pdf->MultiCell(0, $object->height, $object->text, 0, $align, false, 1, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                break;
            case 'image':
                $pdf->setXY($object->left, $object->top);
                $pdf->Rotate(360-$object->angle);
                $pdf->Image($object->src, $object->left, $object->top, $object->width, $object->height, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $pdf->StopTransform();
    }
    $pdf->Close();
    echo $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D');
```

Answer (score 6):

Alright it working, it was very easy to make this code working :D
Left and top are given from the center of the object, so enough of the left marginuse subtract half the width of the object and it works

```
$pdf = new MYPDF("L", "px", array(761, 430), true, 'UTF-8', false, false, $objects->backgroundImage, $objects->background);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(0);
$pdf->SetRightMargin(0);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
#$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
foreach ($objects->objects as $object) {
    $pdf->StartTransform();
    $left = $object->left - ($object->width/2);
    $top = $object->top - ($object->height/2);
    switch ($object->type) {
        case 'text':
            $align = $this->setAlign($object->textAlign);
            $style = $this->setStyle($object->fontStyle);
            $newColor = $this->hex2RGB($object->fill);
            $pdf->setXY($left, $top);
            $pdf->SetFont("times", $style, $object->fontSize);
            $pdf->SetTextColor($newColor['red'], $newColor['green'], $newColor['blue']);
            $pdf->MultiCell(0, $object->height, $object->text, 0, $align, false, 1, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
            break;
        case 'image':
            $pdf->setXY($left, $top);
            $pdf->Rotate(360-$object->angle);
            $pdf->Image($object->src, $object->left, $object->top, $object->width, $object->height, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    $pdf->StopTransform();
}
$pdf->Close();
echo $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D');
```

if someone had a problem with this, the above is the proper code.

Comment: I see that you used **MYPDF** class in your code. Is that some customized version  of **TCPDF** or ? is there any github repo for that ?

Comment: It was similer lib to tcpdf, it was 3 years ago, so probably repo doesn't exists, but you can use any pdf lib generator for php.